# Differentiability and continuity - strictly increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If a function f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,c) and on (c,b) and $f'(x)>0 $ for $x\in(a,c) $ and $x\in(c,b)$ then how can we show that f is strictly increasing on [a,b]?
I know I need to use the fact that f is continuous at c to show this and it is intuitive and seems obvious but how do I show explicitly that $f(c)>f(x)$ if $x\in (a,c)$ and $f(c)<f(x)$ if $x\in (c,b)$?

Comment: Or you can just use the mean value theorem.

Comment: How does one use the mean value theorem to show this?

Comment: Looks like the function is continuous on $[x,c]$ and differentiable on $(x,c)$ so a direct application of mean value theorem would work.  http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der11/der11.html

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f(c) > f(x)$ for all $x<c$, suppose the contrapositive: that there exists $y\in [a,c)$ such that $f(y) \geq f(c)$.

If $f(y) < f(c)$, then in particular, there exists some $z$ such that $f(c) < z < f(y)$, and since $f$ is continuous, the IVT tells us that there exists $w\in (y,c)$ such that $f(w) = z$. Thus, we have that $w > y$, and that $f(w) = z < f(y)$, which contradicts the fact that $f$ is increasing on $(a,c)$. Therefore, the desired fact holds.

If $f(y) = f(c)$, it's easy to show that there exists $y_0\in (y,c)$ such that $f(y) = f(y_0)$ (contradicting that $f$ is increasing on $(a,c)$), or such that $f(y_0) < f(c)$ (getting us back to the previous case).

The proof is similar for the other side of the interval.